# compiling two indicators ( one is on version 3 and other one is one version 4 )

Tags: pine-script

I am new to TradingView Pine scripting. I am working on some study/strategy but currently seeking for help with a pine script which compiles 2 indicators. one of them is on version 3 ( also opens on diffrent pane ) and other is on version 4 ( and opens overlay ) but I am trying to convert the version 3 one into Version 4 and after that will try to see them both overlay

Below is the complete script I am trying to convert

Script

```
//#######################################################

// fisher //

ccilength=input(5, "CCI Length")

wmalength=input(9, title="Smoothing length")

v1=0.1*(cci(close, ccilength)/4)

v2=wma(v1, wmalength)

INV=(exp(2*v2)-1)/(exp(2*v2)+1)

plot(INV, color=red, linewidth=2)

hline(0.5, color=red)

hline(-0.5, color=green)

//#######################################################

// Supertrend //
format=format.price, precision=2, resolution=""

Periods = input(title="ATR Period", type=input.integer, defval=10)

src = input(hl2, title="Source")

Multiplier = input(title="ATR Multiplier", type=input.float, step=0.1, defval=3.0)

changeATR= input(title="Change ATR Calculation Method ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)

showsignals = input(title="Show Buy/Sell Signals ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)

highlighting = input(title="Highlighter On/Off ?", type=input.bool, defval=true)

atr2 = sma(tr, Periods)

atr= changeATR ? atr(Periods) : atr2

up=src-(Multiplier*atr)

up1 = nz(up[1],up)

up := close[1] > up1 ? max(up,up1) : up

dn=src+(Multiplier*atr)

dn1 = nz(dn[1], dn)

dn := close[1] < dn1 ? min(dn, dn1) : dn

trend = 1

trend := nz(trend[1], trend)

trend := trend == -1 and close > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < up1 ? -1 : trend

upPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? up : na, title="Up Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.green)

buySignal = trend == 1 and trend[1] == -1

plotshape(buySignal ? up : na, title="UpTrend Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, transp=0)

plotshape(buySignal and showsignals ? up : na, title="Buy", text="Buy", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)

dnPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? na : dn, title="Down Trend", style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=2, color=color.red)

sellSignal = trend == -1 and trend[1] == 1

plotshape(sellSignal ? dn : na, title="DownTrend Begins", location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, transp=0)

plotshape(sellSignal and showsignals ? dn : na, title="Sell", text="Sell", location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, transp=0)

mPlot = plot(ohlc4, title="", style=plot.style_circles, linewidth=0)

longFillColor = highlighting ? (trend == 1 ? color.green : color.white) : color.white

shortFillColor = highlighting ? (trend == -1 ? color.red : color.white) : color.white

fill(mPlot, upPlot, title="UpTrend Highligter", color=longFillColor)

fill(mPlot, dnPlot, title="DownTrend Highligter", color=shortFillColor)

alertcondition(buySignal, title="SuperTrend Buy", message="SuperTrend Buy!")

alertcondition(sellSignal, title="SuperTrend Sell", message="SuperTrend Sell!")

changeCond = trend != trend[1]

alertcondition(changeCond, title="SuperTrend Direction Change", message="SuperTrend has changed direction!")

//#######################################################
```